# Google App Script for creating listpage listitems

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I think I should be able to add more than one list item at a time using a script such as:

```
page.addListItems([["John", "Smith", "123 Main St"],["John", "Smith", "123 Main St"]];
```

using a google app script.  However, I can only find the function to do this:

```
page.addListItem(["John", "Smith", "123 Main St"]);
```

The problem I find is that adding lists in this manner is very slow (3 seconds/ listitem), and I cannot add more than about 100 listItems before my script times out (at about five minutes).  This could be solved by reducing the number of calls to google scripts - but I need to know the secret code for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reduce the service calls in this case, but there probably should be.

You should enter a feature request in the [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/) for this. Once you do, come back here and publicize the issue number, so others can add their voice.